# Ember CLI tests on Sauce Labs

Tags: javascript, ember-cli, saucelabs, testem

How can I get `ember-cli` tests running on Sauce Labs?  Testem has an [example configuration](https://github.com/airportyh/testem/tree/master/examples/saucelabs), but I don't know how to translate that into the `ember-cli` compiled tests since the `testem.json` gets packed into the build when tests run.

I tried doing an `ember build --env=test` and then putting `"test_page": "dist/tests/index.html"` in my `testem.js` and just running `testem ci --port=8080` as it is in the example, but that gives me 0 tests run.

Comment: I managed to run the tests on Sauce Labs, but sauce labs giving me some proxy error, can you run on SL at all? And did you do `npm install saucie -g`.

Comment: Yes, I installed sauceie globally.  With some work I'm now able to connect, but not point to my tests, it always loads my document root instead of my tests.  I opened an issue with testem which might help: https://github.com/airportyh/testem/issues/422

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I have this mostly solved (some issues remain with individual browsers).  For posterity you can view my solution [here](https://github.com/ilios/frontend/commit/24a9f0641f34a71f83d365f5381c38c1d00c794b)*:

The things that seem to be necessary:

1. Use NVM to manage node on OSX, things only started to work when I stopped having to sudo random junk.
2. Don't use localhost, I used localtest here for the hostname, but you can use anything - sauce and localhost don't get along very well.
3. The command is `ember test --port=8080 --host=localtest`
4. I put my sauce stuff in a different testem config file so I can still run ember test on my dev machine.

Hopefully having a starting place saves someone else from doing all of the wrong things I did originally.

*You probably don't need all of that, as we're currently using ember-cli api stubs to mock our API during development so we need to run a separate instance of ember serve.